# Loop through records and update sql table if exists using Pyodbc or pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I would like to know if there is a way for Python using pyodbc to loop through the records of a table and if it see s a blank (i.e ' ' ) field change the value to null. 
I have a working python script that will list the values in a table . From here not sure how to loop through the rows and determine if the column is filled with spaces and if it is change the value to null. it's basically ssis cleanup stuff but don'w want to go through the hassle of using ssis. wanted to try something with python 
here is the code

```python
import pyodbc
import time
start_time = time.time()

conn = (
  r'Driver={SQL Server};'
  r'Server=<enter Server here>;'
  r'Database=<enter Database here;'
  r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Create SQL Statement to get rows
sql = """
Select UserOrderField2 From TestAccountPD
where UserOrderField2 = ''
"""
# put all into rows variable
rows = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

for row in rows:
  print(row)

cursor.close
cnxn.close()
print("---%s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Use the native SQL. `UPDATE TestAccountPD SET UserOrderField2 = NULL WHERE UserOrderField2 = ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the rows. In fact, you should avoid looping through rows whenever possible because it is almost always *much* slower then performing a single UPDATE operation. In your case that would be something like

```python
sql = """\
UPDATE TestAccountPD SET UserOrderField2 = NULL
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(UserOrderField2)) = 0
"""
cursor.execute(sql)
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked.  I modified it with parameters, but that worked.  Much appreciated.